# I can not save values using POST method - laravel vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to save the data I send from the Event view. in the storeEvent method of the EventController driver but it gives me error 422 and I can not find the problem so far.

The Event model has a many-to-many relationship with the Categories model, and Event also has a many-to-many relationship with the Coins model, which is why I occupy vue-multiselect since the user can select several categories or several coins for the same event

Event.vue

```
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="createdEvent" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label>Titulo</label>
     <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="25" v-model="title">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label>*Cryptodivisas</label>
     <multiselect v-model="coinvalue" :options="coins"
                :multiple="true" label="name" 
                track-by="id" placeholder="Seleccione">
     </multiselect>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label>*Categoría</label>
     <multiselect v-model="categoryvalue" :options="categories"
                :multiple="true" label="name" 
                track-by="id" placeholder="Seleccione">
     </multiselect>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-sm-12">
     <button class="btn" type="submit">Crear evento</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

```js
<script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
    export default {  
      components: { 
        Multiselect,
      },
      props: ['auth'],     
      data () {
        return {
            user:           {},
            title:          '',
            coins:          [],
            coinvalue:      [],
            categories:     [],
            categoryvalue:  [], 
       }
      },
      created() {
        this.getCoins();
        this.getCategories();
      },
      mounted() {
        this.user = JSON.parse(this.auth);
      },
      methods: {
        getCoins(){
            let urlCoin = '/dashboard/coins';
            axios.get(urlCoin)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.coins = response.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                })
        },
        getCategories(){
            let urlCategories = '/dashboard/categories';
            axios.get(urlCategories)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.categories = response.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                })
        },
        createdEvent(){
            let urlEvent = '/dashboard/newEvent';
            const eventData = {
                'id'            : this.user.id,
                'title'         : this.title,
                'coin'          : this.coinvalue,
                'category'      : this.categoryvalue,
            }
            console.log(eventData);
            axios.post(urlEvent, eventData)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(ok);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                })
        }
 </script>
```

storeEvent (EventController)

```
 public function storeEvent(Request $request)
 {
      $this->validate($request, [
                'title'    => 'required|max:25',
                'coin'     => 'required',
                'category' => 'required',
        ]);

        $userAuth = Auth::user()->id;
        $userEvent = $request->id;
        if($userAuth === $userEvent){
            $event = new Event;
            $event->user_id = $userEvent;
            $event->title = $request->title;   
            if($event->save()){
                $event->coins()->attach($request->coin);
                $event->categories()->attach($request->category);
                return response()->json([
                        'status' => 'Muy bien!',
                        'msg' => 'Tu evento ya fue creado con éxito.',
                        ], 200);
            }
            else {
                return response()->json([
                            'status' => 'Error!',
                            'msg' => 'No pudimos crear tu evento.',
                        ], 401);
            }
       }
}
```

I think the problem may be when I assign the values to the coin () -> attach () and category () -> attach () section, but I have no idea how to solve it due to my inexperience in the tool.

The system was made entirely in Laravel and it worked without problems, now that it is being updated with Vue it began to give inconveniences.

Any ideas? I occupy Laravel 5,6, Vuejs 2, Axios and Vue-multiselect 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending form data

Here is the example for you.

```
var urlEvent = '/dashboard/newEvent';

var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('id',this.user.id);
form_data.append('title',this.title);

for(let coin of this.coinvalue)
    form_data.append('coin[]', coin);

for(let category of this.categoryvalue)
    form_data.append('category[]', category);

axios(urlEvent,{
    method: "post",
    data: form_data
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(ok);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data);
});
```

If this stills gives you a 422 status code (Unprocessable entities). Then try returning $request in you controller. And check what data are actually send to the controller and what your validation is.

Comment: Excellent, now my problem is how to save the category data and coin in the tables related to event, I have this code in the `$ event-> coins () -> attach ($ request-> coin); $ event-> categories () -> attach ($ request-> category); `

Comment: If you are using one to many relations. You can just make loop to save it. `foreach($request->coin as $coin)`

Comment: I using many to many relationship between Event to Coin and Event to Category

Comment: Are you sure. `$request->coin` is ids, and saved in coin table. ?

Comment: I solved the problem, the data is saved in the table Event and in the intermediate tables, the problem now is that when the information is saved it returns me a response error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Can not read property 'data' of undefined `

Comment: You better post another question. and mark it as solved. :D

Answer (score 0):

422 means validation error so do a `console.log` or inspect the element on `axios` call and check that :

```
 'title'         : this.title,
 'coin'          : this.coinvalue,
 'category'      : this.categoryvalue,
```

Are not empty, cause right now some data from above is missing since its a `422` validation exception.

Comment: the data from Axios are sent well, the problem is in the controller method